# Jquery's appendTo causes script blocks to be executed again

Tags: jquery

If I use **appendTo** to move parts of the DOM tree around script blocks being moved are rerun, i.e. they run twice.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EHDqE/

Is there a better way to move DOM sections around without script blocks within them being executed again?

Comment: `$("#one").text().appendTo("#two")`

Comment: oh, the script is inside of "one".. do you want that script tag to transfer with it? just not run again?

Comment: No pun indended @Ohgodwhy, but "Oh God! Why?"

Comment: @teewuane Doesn't matter.  I just need the dom to be moved without the scripts being executed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do something similar before... Kind of hacky but... http://jsfiddle.net/teewuane/EHDqE/3/

HTML

```
<div id="one">
 a
 <script type="text/javascript">
     if(times_executed == 0){
         alert(1);
         times_executed+=1;
     } 
 </script>
 </div>
 <div id="two">
  b
 </div>​
```

SCRIPT

```
times_executed = 0;


$("#one").appendTo("#two");​
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, it is not good practice to embed scripts directly into your code.  They should be referenced in your header, and included in a seperate file.

Second, I don't believe it is possible to prevent that script from running again as written, as `appendTo()` does an HTML rewrite of the DOM element you are looking at.  This means you need to access the text directly, rather than the element as a whole.  @Ohgodwhy's solution is correct:

```
$("#one").text().appendTo("#two")
```

However (if this is not a homework problem), I would implore that you consider moving your script to your header, as this is the current best practice.

Comment: The scripts are being dynamically created in a codebehind so they cannot be included in a seperate file.

Comment: @user357320 You could use a low level DOM extractor in your server side code to move all script tags to the head (sequentially) then deliver that file. [Something like this would probably do you very well.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @user357320 can you not create a generic method that does what your codebehind stuff does and pass in parameters?  what you are doing sounds like a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 It is a part of a dynamic form generator and the javascript needs to be dynamically created as jquery code is being created (including function names) for each control instance.

Comment: @ohgodwhy Yes.  Or possibly gather the injected code into a single function which is then called after the appendTo.

Comment: @user357320 Yep, either of those methods should find you reprieve from this template engine you're stuck with.